# "Interact" Button in MoveIt.RViz Plugin

Tags: rviz, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was working through the MoveIt tutorials in which I launched the PR2 configuration demo using the RViz plugin and saw how you could use the 6-DOF interactive markers to move the robot joints.  I then tried to do the same thing for my robot, but the interactive markers don't appear.  Nothing happens when I click on the "Interact" button in RViz.  The button is selected but my mouse cursor still displays as the camera control cursor.

How can I check to see what's preventing RViz from allowing me to interact with my robot?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/114936/%22interact%22-button-in-moveit.rviz-plugin/) by [daalt](https://answers.ros.org/users/9331/daalt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 159 on 2014-01-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, I should note that I did not have an end effector defined. However, the interactive markers appeared after defining one.

---

Originally posted by [daalt](https://answers.ros.org/users/9331/daalt/) with karma: 159 on 2014-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-10-18**:
By your answer I was able to fix the same issue. Notice that parent group is necessary for the `eef` definition.

**Comment by [Markus](https://answers.ros.org/users/26348/markus/) on 2020-03-03**:
It is not working for me as I described here: https://answers.ros.org/question/345685/interactive-marker-not-visible-in-moveit_config/